# Foundation 5.0.3 interfering with mCustomScrollbar on iPad with regards to touch gestures

Tags: ipad, hyperlink, scroll, touch, zurb-foundation

I use the mCustomScrollbar by Malihu in a menu. As soon as I add the foundation.min.js (Foundation 5.0.3) without even calling $(document).foundation(); the touching gets messed up on the iPad 1. Furthermore the first click on a  in the menu will not fire. This happens also on the iPad 3 iOS7.

EDIT: Updated the link which now activates "contentTouchScoll" with no better result.
You can see an example here (open on iPad, click "Projekte" and try to scroll the submenu):
[http://fiddle.jshell.net/matthiasmax/Uqg8f/8/show/](http://fiddle.jshell.net/matthiasmax/Uqg8f/7/show/)

A version WITHOUT Foundation is found here (Scrolling and links working):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/matthiasmax/Uqg8f/6/show/

Any idea how I could make this works or which part of foundation might be causing the problem? I have not tested this on any other tablet than the iPad.

Comment: Does really no one have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: FastClick. This plugin is called by Foundation even if .foundation() ist not called!

You can exclude DOM elements from FastClick by adding the class "needsclick" to them.